# How to change the language of Google speech recognition

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, google-speech-api, french

My code:

```
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        print("You said: " + r.recognize_google(audio) + "in french")
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service")
```

I would like to change the listening language to french. How should i do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

here's [the relevant line of documentataion.](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/speech_recognition/__init__.py#L845)

try `r.recognize_google(audio, language="fr-FR")`

Comment: You  can find all the possible language codes here : https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/languages

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    voise = r.recognize_google(audio, language="fr-FR")
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    speak('understand')
return voise
```